# Design Issue: Trying to avoid code duplication while using Consts

Tags: c#, inheritance, constants

Consider this class diagram:

[image]

Car has a **constant** max speed of 200 kph, and bus 100 kph. I represent this as a const maxSpeed field in the sub-class;

How do I make getMaxSpeed() return this constant. This is a simple example only to illustrate my problem, so duplicating the getMaxSpeed() to every sub-class won't help me.

Is there any way to do it?

I already considered the solution of avoiding consts and using virtual properties, but then every instance of the class will hold a maxSpeed field, which is a waste of space.

Comment: You don't need a field for a virtual property. Just make it `virtual int MaxSpeed { get { return 200; } }`

Comment: that's right. that smells like a solution, although then there is a function call. I wanted consts to make the compiler implant these numbers for me

Comment: If you want a `const`, it can't be virtual. There is no way for the compiler to inline a constant from a derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of making something virtual is that you don't know at compile time what method to call, so there's no way a `const` can be `virtual`. The typical solution to this is to have `abstract public double MaxSpeed { get; }` in your base class and then `override public double MaxSpeed { get { return 200; } }` in your `Car` derived class.

This solution allows a sophisticated JIT compiler to determine that a particular instance of a `Vehicle` is always a `Car` and be able to inline the `get_MaxSpeed` method call (as you were hoping), while still allowing every vehicle to have its own maximum speed.